# System upgrade to latest 20.04

Tags: upgrade, system

Took hard drive out of older 386 machine and installed it in newer with AMD FX4300. System will not let me uggrade to latest install due to 386 limitation . How do I fix that and write out the 386 limit?

Comment: Re-install.  You given no specifics as to your OS & release, but a i386 architecture install needs to be re-installed to change architecture to amd64.

Comment: The duplicate link gives options, myself I believe a re-install is far easier & it's not worth the hassle of trying to migrate an architecture change. You gave no release details, however you can re-install and have it auto-return the same packages (if available in new release & Ubuntu repositories), without touching any user files (assuming desktop apps, as system directories get wiped some server apps will need *confs* restored by you gave no specifics), but you should of course backup regardless as problems can occur (even if unexpected).

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 18.04 flavors are the last supported releases for x86 (32-bit i686) computers.**

your system isn't let you install newer specs OS that has amd64 architecture in i386 compatible hardware due to their addressing capability.

You should try for **18.04 i386** version of **Lubuntu** for less specs. even computers having 1 GB RAM can run lubuntu smoothly too.